# How to lock on lid close in MacOS

Tags: mac, laptop, sleep, lock-screen, lid

I want to play music over Bluetooth while the lid is closed, and I want the laptop to lock when the lid is closed. I'm able to prevent my MacBook from sleeping on lid close with `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1`, though it doesn't lock and it bizarrely keeps the screen on the entire time. I know that I can manually lock with <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

How can I make my MacOS Ventura 13.4 MacBook automatically lock on lid close rather than staying completely on or sleeping?